# .each() only iterating once, or returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I have two "posts" in a list object, which I want to dynamically append along with html elements.

```
    function getPosts(getRecentPost, PostList) {
                if (getRecentPost == true) {
                    //...
                } else {
                    $.each([PostList], function (index, value) {
                        var text1 = '<div class="col-md-3">' +
                            '<label><b>' + value[index].author +'</b></label>' +
                            '<p id="content">' + value[index].content +'</p>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<hr />' +
                            '   ';
                        $(".posts").after(text1);
                    });
                }
            }
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.get("../api/UserEntities/getProfile").then((result) => {
                $("h5").text(result[0][0].name);
                $("#email").text(result[0][0].email);
                $("#phone").text(result[0][0].phone);
                **getPosts(false, result[1]);**
            });
        });
```

Printing out the object gives me the proper list. Printing it by the index (value[index]) only gives me the object at 0. If I remove the brackets on [PostList] I get only undefined, or undefined and one post (depending on if I pass in result[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egYXF.png) or result.

This is what I want to iterate through:
[image: console output of list]

Comment: Since you use `result[0][0]` should it not then be `getPosts(false, result[0][1]);`

Comment: maybe I didn't make it clear enough, but result carries a "full profile", and so result[0][x] is stuff like name and email. result[1][x] is different posts

Comment: What is the picture?`PostList` or `[PostList]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the picture is `PostList` rathar than `[PostList]`

1. try to change `[PostList]` to `PostList`
2. Try to change  `value[index].author` to `value.author`,and change `value[index].content` to  `value.content`.

If the picture is `[PostList]`,you only need to change  `value[index].author` to `value.author`,and change `value[index].content` to  `value.content`.
Here is a demo:
Controller:

```
public List<Post> GetPostList()
        {
            List<Post> l = new List<Post> {
                new Post{ postID=1, authorID=23,author="dsdss",title="ba", content="yooo"},
                new Post{ postID=2, authorID=22,author="aaa",title="aaaba", content="rewreyooo"},

            };

            return l;
        }
```

View:

```
<div>
    <p class="posts">posts</p>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
         $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetPostList", "Test1")',
               
         }).done(function (data) {
             getPosts(false, data);
            });
    })
    function getPosts(getRecentPost, PostList) {
        if (getRecentPost == true) {
            //...
        } else {
            $.each(PostList, function (index, value) {
                var text1 = '<div class="col-md-3">' +
                    '<label><b>' + value.author + '</b></label>' +
                    '<p id="content">' + value.content + '</p>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<hr />' +
                    '   ';
                $(".posts").after(text1);
            });
        }
    }

    </script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: It worked, thanks. I'm left with the question; whats index for? Can't I just omit it?

Comment: You can refer to the [link](https://api.jquery.com/each/).And we don't have a method like `$.each(PostList, function (value) `.